# Using javascript to set Struts select list headerKey and headerValue

Tags: javascript, select, struts2, struts

I have a Struts select list however i would like to use javascript to set selected option to the default headerKey and headerValue specified when creating the item. I am unable to get the option to set. Under is my select list:

**Struts Select List**

```
<s:select id="relationshipTypeId"
name="relationshipTypelist" headerKey= "0" headerValue="Select Relationship Type"
list="relationshipTypelist"
listKey="id" listValue="relationshipName"/>
```

**Javascript**

This does not work it only sets the display item to 0 i would like it to default to the headerKey and headerValue.

```
  document.getElementById('relationshipTypeId').value = 0;
```

Comment: Your code should work. BTW it is strange to use the same attribute for both `list` and `name`: the first is the collection you are showing from the first action, the second is the selected value to send to the target action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me after i posted this question

```
document.getElementById('relationshipTypeId').setAttribute('value',0);
```